# Can't get mod_wsgi to work with Apache and Django on Mac OS X

Tags: django, macos, apache, mod-wsgi

I've been trying to get mod_wsgi working on a Mac OS X server, and I'm having absolutely no luck.  I've added the LoadModule statement to the httpd.conf, and I've got the following file included:

```
apache_django_wsgi.conf:

WSGIDaemonProcess django
WSGIProcessGroup django

Alias /plagtest/ "/Users/plagtest/myproject/"
<Directory "/Users/plagtest/myproject/">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /plagtest "/Users/plagtest/myproject/apache/myproject.wsgi"

<Directory "/Users/plagtest/myproject/apache">
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And here's my WSGI file:

```
myproject.wsgi:

import os
import sys

paths = [ '/Users/plagtest/myproject',
          '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
          '/Users/plagtest',
]

for path in paths:
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)

sys.executable = '/usr/local/bin/python2.7'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I can restart Apache just fine, but when I browse to localhost/plagtest/ it comes up file not found, and this is what I get in the error log:

```
File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/Documents/plagtest/
```

I'm not entirely familiar with Apache, and I'm sure that it's probably something very simple, but I can't for the life of me find a solution online.  Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have two Aliases for the same path.  So hence you have a duplication.  Remove:

```
Alias /plagtest/ "/Users/plagtest/myproject/"
<Directory "/Users/plagtest/myproject/">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>
```

Without the media alias's the django manuals recommended HTTP conf is:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: I made these changes, and still no luck.  I'm still seeing the same 'File Not Found' error in the logs :(

Comment: No wait, forgot to restart Apache :/
That did do the trick.  Thanks!